# Change UIButton's state from a different View Controller - Swift 4.2

Tags: uibutton, game-center, appdelegate, swift4.2

I have `gameCenterButton` in VC1. Its purpose is to take the  user to Game Center's Leaderboards where they can see High Scores. If the user decides to authenticate with Game Center, then I want to change `gameCenterButton`'s state (un-grey and enable). In my `GameKitHelper` class I have these:

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer() {

    GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler =
        { (viewController, error) in

            self.gameCenterEnabled = false
            if viewController != nil {

                self.authenticationViewController = viewController
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(
                    GameKitHelper.PresentAuthenticationViewController),
                                                object: self)
            } else if GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated {

                self.gameCenterEnabled = true
            }
    }
}

extension GameKitHelper: GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

In VC1 I have this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gameCenterButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func gameCenter(_ sender: UIButton) {

    GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.showGKGameCenterViewController(viewController: self)

}
```

I'm thinking that inside of `extension GameKitHelper` I can do ...

```
if gameCenterEnabled == true {

    gameCenterButton.isEnabled = true  // How do I allow for this?

    gameCenterButton.alpha = 1  // How do I allow for this?
```

How do I allow `gameCenterButton` state to change outside of it's class. Is there something I need to do in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: You probably shouldn't change the button outside its class.  Can you go the other direction and have the controller ask the helper for `gameCenterEnabled` state whenever the controller's  content is displayed?

Comment: If I create a global variable, equal it to gameCenterEnabled, put it in VC1, and create a conditional if statement using the global variable to change the button’s state, then I still run into a big problem. Where would I put this code? I can’t put it in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, or viewDidLayoutSubviews, because the state of the button is dependent upon the user’s decision to authenticate or not. And this decision will take place after those functions have already ocurred.

Comment: The determination of whether the user authenticated or not takes place in GameKitHelper, that’s why I thought I would change the button’s state there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `var gameCenterEnabled = false` outside (above) of your `GameKitHelper` class, thus making it "global". You will likely be prompted to remove the `self.` in `self.gameCenterEnabled = false` and in `self.gameCenterEnabled = true`. Do so.

Now, you can reference `gameCenterEnabled` in `VC1`'s class and change `gameCenterButton`'s state like this:

```
        // code to determine gameCenterButton's state based on gameCenterEnabled's status
        if gameCenterEnabled == false {

            self.gameCenterButton.isEnabled = false
            self.gameCenterButton.alpha = 0.37  
        } else {
            self.gameCenterButton.isEnabled = true
            self.gameCenterButton.alpha = 1
        }
```